# gridview check duplicates not using sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, foreach, duplicates

I have a code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow dr in gvCategories.Rows)<br/>
{  
   <br/>
   if (dr.Cells[0].Text == txtEnterCategory.Text.Trim())<br/>
   <br/>
    isError=true;
   <br/>
   <br/> 
}
```

Debugging: `dr.Cells[0].Text` is always `""`, even there are records. How to use a loop to check each row to find if a record exists in the gridview not using sql?

More code:

in *.ascx*:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category Name" SortExpression="Category">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="txtCategoryEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CategoryName") %>' OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCategoryEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CategoryName") %>' OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="In Footer?" SortExpression="ShowInFooter">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblShowInFooter" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# (bool)Eval("ShowInFooter") ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="lblShowInFooter" runat="server"
      Checked='<%# (bool)Eval("ShowInFooter")%>'>
    </asp:CheckBox>

  </EditItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>


 <asp:CommandField ShowCancelButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" CausesValidation="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="commandfield" />
</Columns>
```

in *ascx.cs*:

```
bool isError = false;

foreach (GridViewRow dr in gvCategories.Rows)
    {
        if (dr.Cells[0].Text == txtEnterCategory.Text.Trim())
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "This category already exits. Please enter a new category!";
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;

            isError=true;

        }


    }
```

Comment: On what event are you running that code?

Comment: button click after adding a category

Comment: Can we see the ASPX markup for gvCategories?  If there's a button in the leftmost column you'd get this behaviour.

Comment: I was actually hoping to see the contents of the <Columns> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got a TemplateField containing a Label in the leftmost column, rather than a BoundField, you get the value out like this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow dr in gvCategories.Rows)
{
    Label l = (Label)dr.Cells[0].Controls[1];

    if (l.Text.Trim() == txtEnterCategory.Text.Trim())
    {
        lblErrorMessage.Text = "This category already exits. Please enter a new category!";
        lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;

        isError=true;
    }
```

Don't ask me why it's Controls[1], but it is.  Every control in a TemplateField's ItemTemplate seems to create a pair of controls, so for example, if you had this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFoo" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBar" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

txtFoo would be at Controls[1] and txtBar would be at Controls[3].

Comment: well, it's label actually, which turns to texbox when u click EDIT. So now I get casting error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

Comment: Try Label l = (Label)dr.Cells[0].Controls[1]; instead?

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked :)  I'll edit the answer to reflect the fact that you've got a Label in there instead of a TextBox.